# java (matcher.group()) - write to file

Tags: java, string, file, matcher

I have code that finds coordinates between specific words.
Now, output to console works perfect, but id like to output the matches found TO FILE
My current code:

```
public class Filetostring {


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String s = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
//System.out.println(content);


    Pattern patt;
    patt = Pattern.compile("\\bworld\\b|\\bsolid\\b|.(-?\\d+\\s-?\\d+\\s-?\\d+\\)\\s\\     (-?\\d+\\s-?\\d+\\s-?\\d+\\)\\s\\(-?\\d+\\s-?\\d+\\s-?\\d+).");
    Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find())
//System.out.println(matcher.group());


try (FileWriter file2 = new FileWriter("output.txt"); 
        BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(file2)) {
        bf.write(matcher.group());
}

        System.out.println("Done");

}

        }
```

Output should be

world

solid

(3245) (2334) (-234)

.

.

.

.

.

.

(457) (2) (2323)

instead, when i output to file, only the first coords appear:

(3245) (2334) (-234)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, you are opening the same file through each pass through the while loop.  Each `FileWriter/BufferedWriter` combo will write one line of output.  None are ever closed.  When they finally are released, it's going to be a guessing game as to which one get flushed & closed last, overwriting all the other outputs.

Try moving the `while` loop inside the `try`, after the `BufferedWriter` is created.  And then close `bf` when done (in a `finally` block would be nice).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Only issue is that the output is in one line

Comment: Try using a PrintWriter and its `println` method.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

Comment: That worked great!
            PrintWriter bf = new PrintWriter(file2)) {
            while (matcher.find())
            bf.println(matcher.group());
            
            bf.close();